# Tablix report with multiple tables linked together

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I want to create tablix report in the following format:

Where Customer / Orders / Inquiries are seperate tables with customer ID as primary key. How can I create this kind of tablix report where I can display all information in single row by customer ID?

[Link to the report format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt0a9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create one dataset that joins all the tables together you could create multiple datasets one for customer, orders, and inquiries and use the lookup and lookupset function by passing in the CustomerID to each.
You would paste expressions that look similar to these in the textboxes of the table

Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
LookupSet(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)

=JOIN(LookupSet(Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!OrdersthisQuarter.Value, "orders"),"")

=JOIN(LookupSet(Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!InquiriesthisQuarter.Value, "inquiries"),"")

=Lookup(Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!Contact.Value, "orders")

=Lookup(Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value, Fields!Region.Value, "inquiries")

[Lookup Function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)

[LookupSet Function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to write a query that joins all the tables and creates a data set. I would recommend using stored procedure for your query.
2. Add data set & data source to SSRS.
3. Create the tablix report.

Please make your data set does not return to many rows because it will complicate browsing & export performance.

More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ! I am confused/having trouble with joining multiple tables in a single query and creating dataset out of that (step 1 of your answer). I would appreciate if you can point me to any good reference to create this kind of query (with or without stored procedure).

Comment: Also when I join the tables there are multiple rows for single customer. Since they have multiple orders / inquiries. How can i merge them in single row in the tablix ?

Comment: When you build your table, create a group on customer ID and that should roll up to one customer and will display the multiple orders and inquiries they have. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220470.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Heres a reference to  creating a dataset in SSRS. [SSRS Dataset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160345%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

I"m assuming you're query and the embedded dataset code would look something like this if you join on cusotmerID:

```
SELECT customerID

,customername

,contact

,region

,ordersthisquarter

,inquiriesthisquarter

FROM Customer C WITH (NOLOCK)

JOIN Orders o WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID

JOIN inquiries i WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

if you paste this as a dataset you can use the fields from this dataset on a tablix.
When you build your table, create a group on customer ID and that should roll up to one customer and will display the multiple orders and inquiries they have. [creating groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220470.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ! that worked but only thing i could not do was group by multiple fields :( However, the other method mentioned by you worked like a charm. Not sure which method is efficient but i am going with Lookupset for now.. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: This method above is probably more efficient as Lookup/LookupSet may take some time to render/ will have performance issues if dealing with lots of data. If you won't have too many results in the query then no need to worry.